# Why Python on Windows can't read an image in binary mode?

Tags: python, image, binary

I want to read a image in binary mode so that I could save it into my database, like this:

```
img = open("Last_Dawn.jpg")
t = img.read()
save_to_db(t)
```

This is working on Mac. But on Windows, what img.read() is incorrect. It's just a little out of the whole set.

So my first question is: why code above doesn't work in Windows?

And second is: is there any other way to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't say for sure but I do know that the ISO C standard doesn't distinguish between the binary and non-binary modes when calling `fopen` and yet Windows *does*.

It's likely that the Python code just uses `fopen("Last_Dawn.jpg","r")` under the covers (since it's written in C) and this is being opened in Windows in non-binary mode.

This will most likely convert line end characters (`LF -> CRLF`) and possibly others.

If you yourself specify the mode as 'rb' on your open statement, that should fix it:

```
img = open("Last_Dawn.jpg", "rb")
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to open in binary mode:

```
img = open("Last_Dawn.jpg", 'rb')
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to tell Python to open the file in binary mode:

```
img = open('whatever.whatever', 'rb')
```

See the documentation for the open function here: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open

Answer (score 2):

```
open(filename, 'rb')
```